# PHP Mailer e-mail sent but not received

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHP mailer to send an e-mail.

PHP mailer debug is telling me this:

```
2020-04-08 10:16:59 Connection: opening to 192.***.**.**:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-04-08 10:16:59 Connection: opened
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SRVEX01.***.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 8 Apr 2020 12:16:59 +0200
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO ncrapp.***.nl
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SRVEX01.***.local Hello [192.168.50.31]250-SIZE 104857600250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS250-AUTH NTLM250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 XRDST
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<Flow.Info@***.nl>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<rob@***.nl>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<ronnie@***.nl>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<koen@***.nl>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 8 Apr 2020 12:16:59 +0200
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: rob@***.nl, ronnie@***.nl, koen@***.nl
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Flow.Info@***.nl
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Test Mail
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <mUgoSkvhJrgVz1iGjf0wTNZ0RPaIWMxpxujmhFRzdw@ncrapp.***.nl>
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: Test Mail
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.6.0 <mUgoSkvhJrgVz1iGjf0wTNZ0RPaIWMxpxujmhFRzdw@ncrapp.***.nl> [InternalId=108795816574987, Hostname=SRVEX01.***.local] 1719 bytes in 0.096, 17,471 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
2020-04-08 10:16:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-04-08 10:16:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2020-04-08 10:16:59 Connection: closed
```

I've multiple e-mail addresses where I sent the e-mail to. 
Everything seems to be okay, but some mail addresses never received the e-mail.

Me (Rob) received the e-mail but the other 2 employees did not receive an e-mail. 
The company where I'm a trainee for has around 100 employees, 10 of them can not receive an e-mail from my application.

Is this a programming problem? Or a mail server problem?

My code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->Host = "192.***.**.**";
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Username = "***";
$mail->Password = "***";
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->addAddress("rob@***.nl");
$mail->addAddress("ronnie@***.nl");
$mail->addAddress("koen@***.nl");

$mail->setFrom('Flow.Info@***.nl');

$mail->Subject = "Test Mail";
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Body = "Test Mail";

$mail->send();
```

Comment: The problem is from the port of the email or port for the webmaster your sending to. One of them is refusing the other port

Comment: If just one person received the email, then it is working.  What SMTP server are you sending do?  192 sounds internal (though may not be).  Are you using the same mail server as the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debugging**

**Enabling less secure apps to access Gmail**

Open your Google Admin console (admin.google.com).

Click Security > Basic settings .

Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps .

In the subwindow, select the Enforce access to less secure apps for all users radio button. ...

Click the Save button.

**USING LATEST PHPMAILER CODE**

````
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You're delivering to your local mail server successfully, and after that point your script has no further involvement - the mail server is responsible for everything after that, so you need to look at your mail server's logs to see what is happening to messages after that, or pass bounces back from your mail server to your script environment.

You're also running a fairly old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade.